# multiple document.getElementById for var

Tags: javascript

Hello i want to use "var" on multiple Id´s.

```js
// Get modal element
var modal = document.getElementById('modal1');
// Get open modal button
var modalBtn = document.getElementById('Info1');
// Get close button
var closeBtn = document.getElementById('closeBtn1');
```

This is the code that works, but i want to do is that it is "modal1, modal2 ... and Info1, Info2...

Can you help me with that?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow!  You might want to review [ask] for tips on how to better form your question.  As it is currently posed, it is not completely clear on what behavior you are looking to achieve.  Well-formed questions help ensure you will get useful, helpful answers.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Google "JavaScript arrays"

Answer (score 0):

Hey Celtor you can find basic knowledge about JavaScript Variables
in [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp).

then to do so you can use for loop with array as so:

```
// Create list of modals with 15 undefined elements
var modals = Array(15);

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

  // Assign the elemets to the list in their index
  modals[i] = document.getElementById('modal'+i);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a function like this:

```
var getElementsByIds = function(ids){

    var elements = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
        elements[ids[i]] = document.getElementById(ids[i]);
    }

    return elements;    
}
```

This will return an array in which each key is an element you specified, and the key is the element's ID.